# Is the space of Euclidean polyhedra with a fixed $1$-skeleton connected?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, polyhedra

Let $\mathcal{A}_\Gamma$ be the space of convex (non-degenerate) Euclidean polyhedra with $1$-skeleton a certain polyhedral graph $\Gamma$. This space can be seen as a subset of $\mathcal{Gr}_2(\mathbb{R}^3)^F$ where $F$ is the number of faces of $\Gamma$.

It is a well known fact (for example in Proposition 17 of [Deformations of hyperbolic convex polyhedra and cone-$3$-manifolds](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0903.4743.pdf) by Montcouquiol) that $\mathcal{A}_\Gamma$ is a manifold.

**Question:** Is $\mathcal{A}_\Gamma$ connected?

My gut tells me the answer is yes but I couldn't find an easy proof nor a reference.

**Bonus questions:** Is it simply connected? Contractible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your question asks about *isotopy*:

> **Isotopy property**: A combinatorial structure (such as a combinatorial type of
> polytope) has the isotopy property if any two realizations with the same orientation can be deformed into each other by a continuous deformation that maintains
> the combinatorial type. Equivalently, the isotopy property holds for a combinatorial structure if and only if its realization space is connected.

This definition is quoted from "Basic Properties of Convex Polytopes"
by Martin Henk, Jürgen Richter-Gebert, and Günter M. Ziegler, in
*Handbook of Discrete and Computational Geometry*, 2017.
[CRC link](https://www.routledge.com/Handbook-of-Discrete-and-Computational-Geometry-Third-Edition/Toth-ORourke-Goodman/p/book/9781498711395).

Although the isotopy property holds for $3$-polytopes (Steinitz's Theorem),
it was proved by Richter-Gebert that it fails
(quite badly) in dimension $4$.
This is his "Universality Theorem."

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have a follow-up: I have seen Steinitz's Theorem stated roughly as "A graph is the $1$-skeleton of a $3$-polytope if and only if it is planar and $3$-connected". How does this relate to the Isotopy property?

Comment: @GiulioBelletti: I would have to look up the original Satz to be certain, but I believe Steinitz also proved the realization space is $\mathbb{R}^k$ where $k$ depends on the number of edges. (I realize this does not fully answer your followup question.)

Comment: @GiulioBelletti: 2nd try on your followup. One proof approach for Steinitz's theorem is via framework equilibrium stresses. Planar graphs with a self-stress with positive weights are Schlegel diagrams, which when lifted form a polyhedron. Varying the weights results in different realizations. The space of realizations is $\mathbb{R}^{E-6}$ where $E$ is the number of edges.

Comment: I'm still confused about the dimension. If the space of realizations of a graph is $\mathbb{R}^{E-6}$ then for the tetrahedron it would be a single point; however I expect there to be 12 degrees of freedom for tetrahedra in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (6 if we consider them up to isometry)

Comment: @GiulioBelletti: I *think* the discrepancy is that all is "up to projective equivalence," and all tetrahedra are projectively equivalent.